# How to make ifttt posts to Facebook look like the manually added?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, if-this-then-that

I'm trying to post blog updates to a Facebook fan page and my ifttt.com task is set up like this:

[image]

But the result is not the same as manually adding a link from Facebook itself. I've create a picture to illustrate that:

[image]

Is there a way to make ifttt post look exactly the same as manually added FB link? If not, can you recommend some other service that would do it "properly"?

Comment: There's no way. IFTTT uses an API to post content so the settings aren't available to you.

Comment: Just to make sure, are IFTTT using the API correctly? I mean, is it a limitation of the API or an incorrect use?

Comment: It's either the way Facebook's API takes in posts or some misconfiguration on IFTTT side. Either way, there's nothing you can do on your end other then asking IFTTT to look into it.

Comment: @dnbrv you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this as the web app uses the Facebook API to communicate with Facebook. There could be a way to set up sending parameters to the sharer url but I wouldn't recommend it. The correct way to automate posts is via the API and as such they will not be seen as sent by a regular user.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just use the message option instead of posting a link and add the title and the link, simple as that.
I am sharing my recipe: https://ifttt.com/recipes/114206